# Angularjs $http.post call is hitting server twice when network drops and reconnects

Tags: angularjs, wcf

I made $http.post call from client and disconnected my network immediately before getting successCallback. I can see that, the call is hitting my server.

After 2 minutes I have connected the client network back, then the same call is hitting the server again with same arguments. Now client is getting the successCallback and everything looks fine in client side.

Client side log says that, the call has fired only once.

The above $http.post call will send an email to other client. Since the call is hitting the server twice, email is sent twice with 2 minutes time difference.

I am using chrome version 56 and communicating database via WCF.

How to sove this ?